# Jquery - How to make a menu button removeClass when I scroll?

Tags: jquery, css, class, menu

So I have a single-page site that scrolls to various sections when you click a button on the menu at the top.  I've used the code below to toggle the class of whatever button that gets clicked, changing its appearance.

The problem is, if the user then decides to **manually** scroll to another section, I want the button to lose that class so that it goes back to its old appearance.

Also, if the user manually scrolls all the way to the top, I want the "Home" button to regain the class.

...In other words, at (document).ready I add the "buttonActive" class to the Home button, so the visitor knows where they are...

```
$("#menu-item-124 a").addClass("buttonActive");
```

...And when they click a button to get to a lower section, the button they clicked gets the "buttonActive" class...

```
$("ul.menu li a").click(function() {
  $("ul.menu li a").not(this).removeClass("buttonActive");
  $(this).toggleClass("buttonActive");
});
```

...but when the user scrolls to another section **manually**, how can I get the button to now lose the "buttonActive" class?

...and when the user manually scrolls all the way back to the top, how can I get the "Home" button to regain the "buttonActive" class?

All help appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the $( window ).scroll() function.

1. Add "buttonActive" class to the home link.
2. Add a scroll event listener on the window
3. If the window scroll position( $( window ).scrollTop(); ) is equal to 0 or less than the first section offset ( $( '.section1' ).offset().top ) then remove the "buttonActive" class from all links in "#menu-item-124" and add "buttonActive" class to the Home link.
4. If the scroll position is greater than section1 offset and less than section2 offset, then remove "buttonActive" class from all links and add "buttonActive" class to the respective link of section1.
5. Likewise can be taken up for rest of the sections.

Created a mock-up :

HTML :

```
<div class='main-container'>
      <div id="menu-item-124">
        <a class="buttonActive">Home</a>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a>Section1</a></li>
          <li><a>Section2</a></li>
          <li><a>Section3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="home">
      </div>
      <div class="section1">
      </div>
      <div class="section2">
      </div>
      <div class="section3">
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#menu-item-124 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
}

#menu-item-124 ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#menu-item-124 a {
  display: inline;
}

#menu-item-124 ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.home {
  background-color: white;
  height: 600px;
}

.section1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 600px;
}

.section2 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 600px;
}

.section3 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 600px;
}

.buttonActive {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() < $('.section1').offset().top) {
    $("#menu-item-124 a").removeClass("buttonActive");
    $("#menu-item-124 a:eq(0)").addClass("buttonActive");
  } else if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('.section1').offset().top && $(this).scrollTop() < $('.section2').offset().top) {
    $("#menu-item-124 a").removeClass("buttonActive");
    $(".menu li:eq(0) a").addClass("buttonActive");
  } else if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('.section2').offset().top && $(this).scrollTop() < $('.section3').offset().top) {
    $("#menu-item-124 a").removeClass("buttonActive");
    $(".menu li:eq(1) a").addClass("buttonActive");
  } else if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('.section2').offset().top) {
    $("#menu-item-124 a").removeClass("buttonActive");
    $(".menu li:eq(2) a").addClass("buttonActive");
  }
});
```

[JS Fiddle :](https://jsfiddle.net/8ugo5t22/1/)
Just created a rough mock-up. The code provided can be improved a lot. Just gives the idea about how to achieve what you are trying.

Thx

Comment: Thank you.  I haven't had a chance to try this yet, but I will soon.